# Limiting zoom in/out scale change in OxyPlot

Tags: winforms, oxyplot

Using the default PlotController bindings in OxyPlot, one can zoom in/out using the mouse wheel (See http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/controllers/).
What would be the best way to limit the zoom scale ? If I add a listener to the Axis and listen for AxisChanged events, it is too late. Should I intercept mouse wheel events at the Windows Forms level and do something ?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to work with the **Axis.MinimumRange** property for limiting zoom in and the **Axis.MaximumRange** one for limiting zoom out ? This is for limiting the scale. 
*E.g. With the maximum range at 10, the plot zooming may display values from -5 to 5 as well as from 0 to 10 for that axis or -3 to 3.*

Otherwise if the range has to be limited, **Axis.AbsoluteMaximum** and **Axis.AbsoluteMinimum** may be what you are looking for.
*E.g. With absolute minimum at -5 and absolute maximum at 5, the plot may display values from -5 to 5 or -3 to 3 but will not do so from 0 to 10.*